# Decorator to invoke instance method

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a class `A` with method `do_something(self,a,b,c)` and another instance  method that validates the input and check permissions named `can_do_something(self,a,b,c)`.

This is a common pattern in my code and I want to write a decorator that accepts a validation function name and perform the test.

```
def validate_input(validation_fn_name):
        def validation_decorator(func):
            def validate_input_action(self,*args):
                error = getattr(self,validation_fn_name)(*args)
                if not error == True:
                    raise error
                else:
                    return func(*args)
            return validate_input_action
        return validation_decorator
```

Invoking the functions as follows

```
@validate_input('can_do_something')
def do_something(self,a,b,c):
   return a + b + c
```

Problem is that i'm not sure how to maintain `self` through out the validation function. I've used the validation fn name with `getattr` so the fn could be ran in the context of the instance but i cannot do that for `func(*args)`.

So what is the proper way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

So following @André Laszlo answer I realized that self is just the first argument so there is no need to use `getattr` at all but just pass on the `*args`.

```
def validate_input(validation_fn):
    def validation_decorator(func):
        def validate_input_action(*args):
            error = validation_fn(*args)
            if not error == True:
                raise error
            else:
                return func(*args)
        return validate_input_action
    return validation_decorator
```

Much more elegant and it also supports static methods as well.

Adding a static method to @André Laszlo example proves the decorator is working :

```
 class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def validate_baz(a,b,c):
       if a > b:
          return ValueError('a gt b')

    @staticmethod
    @validate_input(Foo.validate_baz)
    def baz(a,b,c):
       print a,b,c

    >>> Foo.baz(1,2,3)
    1 2 3
    >>> Foo.baz(2,1,3)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 6, in validate_input_action
    ValueError: a gt b
```

But, when i'm trying to do them same thing in a django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

class Dummy(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def can_say_name(self):
        if name is None:
            return Exception('Does not have a name')

    @validate_input(can_say_name)
    def say_name(self):
        print self.name

    @staticmethod
    def can_create_dummy(name):
        if name == 'noname':
            return Exception('No name is not a name !')

    @staticmethod
    @validate_input(Dummy.can_create_dummy)
    def create_dummy(name):
        return Dummy.objects.create(name=name)
```

I get the following :

```
NameError: name 'Dummy' is not defined
```

So what is the different between a django model and an Object in relation to this issue ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're coding a lot of js? :)

Comment: I guess. Why you ask ?

Comment: Just thought I recognized a pattern. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
def validate_input(validation_fn_name):
    def validation_decorator(func):
        def validate_input_action(self, *args):
            error = getattr(self, validation_fn_name)(*args)
            if error is not None:
                raise error
            else:
                arglist = [self] + list(args)
                return func(*arglist)
        return validate_input_action
    return validation_decorator

class Foo(object):

    def validate_length(self, arg1):
        if len(arg1) < 3:
            return ValueError('%r is too short' % arg1)

    @validate_input('validate_length')
    def bar(self, arg1):
        print "Arg1 is %r" % arg1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    f.bar('hello')
    f.bar('')
```

Output is:

```
Arg1 is 'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "validator.py", line 27, in <module>
    f.bar('')
  File "validator.py", line 6, in validate_input_action
    raise error
ValueError: '' is too short
```

**Updated answer**

The error (`NameError: name 'Dummy' is not defined`) occurs because the `Dummy` class is not defined yet when the `validate_input` decorator gets `Dummy` as an argument. I guess this could have been implemented differently, but for now that's the way Python works. The easiest solution that I see is to stick to using `getattr`, which will work because it looks up the method at run time.

Comment: Thanks @Andre, I just updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I [tested it](http://pastebin.com/wjhFuwig) and it doesn't work for me, are you sure you were using the new definition of `validate_input` in your interactive session?

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't. Can you think of a way i can make it work for both static and instance methods ?